# Entry count not working with \pgls (glossaries-prefix)

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

I want to use both glossaries-extra and glossaries-prefix. The former for entry counting and only displaying acronyms that appear 3 or more times in the text with the command `\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting{acronym}{2}`.
The latter for using the correct prefix (a vs an) for acronyms starting with M,N,S, etc. so "an" is used for the short forms and "a" for the long forms of those acronyms. (It's an MNE vs a multinational enterprise).
But glossaries-prefix seems not to be compatible with the `\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting{acronym}{2}` command.
How than this be achieved?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[%
    xindy,              % sorting
    acronym,            % additional acronyms list
    nonumberlist,   % no page numbers in glossaries 
    ]{glossaries-extra,glossaries-prefix}
    \RestoreAcronyms    %use original acronym interface instead of abbreviation
    \setglossarystyle{index}

% Only add acronyms to list if trigger value is exceeded
\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting{acronym}{2}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}} % Acronyms bold (in list)

\makeglossaries

\newacronym[
    prefixfirst={a\ },%prefix on first use
    prefix={an\ },%prefix on subsequent uses
%   shortplural={},
%   longplurarl={},
%   name={},%acronym in list
%   description={},%description or long acronym in list
    ]{SDG}%label
    {SDG}%short
    {sustainable development goal}%long

\newacronym[
    prefixfirst={a\ },%prefix on first use
    prefix={an\ },%prefix on subsequent uses
    ]{MNE}%label
    {MNE}%short
    {multinational enterprise}%long


\begin{document}

    \printacronyms[
        nopostdot,      % no dots after items
        style=long,     %
        nogroupskip,    % no space between different groups(letters)
    ]%

    \section{GLS}

    First use of gls \gls{MNE} and 2nd use of \gls{MNE}.


    \section{PGLS}
 
    Example of \pgls{SDG}.


\end{document}
```

Document output:

[image: Document output]

Thanks!

Comment: Hm, interesting, in my case (also with prefix; with extra (1.38) and glossaries 4.42) it's kind of the other way: if used once, only the *short* version is used :)